# how to change style in input tag after some specified text in React Js?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, text-styling

I am trying to make an infinite list by using react js, and tailwind CSS, I am using an input tag to change dynamically data in the specified list. But, I also want to make a suggestion. If there is <> included in the word like if there is a<>b<>c<> then <>b<>c<> or b<>c<> should be blue. I tried using after pseudo-element but it's not working. sharing whole code and input tag included in ----- highlight given below.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { AiOutlinePlus} from 'react-icons/ai';
import "./AddList.css";

const AddList = () => {
const [text,setText]=useState({
  note:"",
});
const [list,setList]=useState([]);
const [showSuggestion,setShowSuggestion]=useState(false);
const[suggesttedData,setSuggestedData]=useState([]);
const[indexed,setIndexed]=useState(0);





const onChange=(e)=>{

    setText(
      {...text,[e.target.name]: e.target.value}
    )

}

const addList=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setList(prev=>[...prev,text]);
    console.log(list);
    setText({
      note:""
    })
  
}

const onchangeInput=(ind)=>{
  setIndexed(ind);
const value=event.target.value;


  const updatedList=list.map((element,index)=>{

   return ind===index?{...element,note:value}:element;

  })
// console.log(updatedList);
  setList([...updatedList]);
  if(updatedList[ind].note.includes("<>"))
  {
    
    setShowSuggestion(true);
    // console.log("Yes");
    const newList = list.slice(ind + 1).map((element) => {
      return element;
    });

    // console.log(newList);
    setSuggestedData([...newList]);

    
       
      
    
  }
  else
  {
    setShowSuggestion(false);
    // console.log("No");
  }
  
}

const changeListData=(ind,value)=>{

   console.log(indexed);
   let addedData="";

   suggesttedData.slice(ind+1).map((element) => {
   addedData+="<>"+element.note;
  });
  console.log(addedData);
   const updatedList=list.map((element,index)=>{
  //  console.log(ind,index);
    const char=element.note;

    return indexed===index?{...element,note:char+value+addedData}:element;
 
   })

setList([...updatedList]);
setShowSuggestion(false);
}
  return (
    <>
    <div className='flex justify-center items-center gap-2'>
    <input  
    className='placeholder:italic placeholder:text-slate-400 block bg-white border border-slate-300 rounded-md py-2 pl-9 pr-3 shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-1 sm:text-sm ' 
      type="text"
      name="note"  
      placeholder='Enter a List...' 
      onChange={onChange}
      value={text.note}
     />
    <div className='flex bg-emerald-200 rounded-full py-2 pl-3 pr-3  justify-center items-center cursor-pointer' 
    onClick={addList} >
        <AiOutlinePlus size={18}/>
        <button  >Add</button>
    </div>
   </div>
 <div >
 {showSuggestion && (
          <ul className= 'fixed right-40 top-28 bg-slate-300 w-24'>
              {suggesttedData.map((suggestion, index) => (
               
               <li
                  key={index}
                  className="cursor-pointer transition-colors duration-300 hover:text-blue-600 "
                  onClick={()=>{
                     
                    changeListData(index,suggestion.note);
                  }}
                >
                  {suggestion.note}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
 </div>
   

   <div className="m-20 mx-auto max-w-screen-md ">
  <div className={` block max-w-md mx-auto p-10 rounded-md ${list.length>0&&`shadow-md`} overflow-y-auto max-h-60 custom-scrollbar`}>
   
    {

      list.map((element,index)=>{

      return (
      <div key={index+1}>
//This is input tag
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       <input type="text" className="font-bold peer h-full border-b border-blue-gray-200 bg-transparent pt-4 pb-1.5 font-sans text-sm  text-blue-gray-700 outline outline-0 transition-all placeholder-shown:border-blue-gray-200 focus:border-pink-500 focus:outline-0 disabled:border-0 disabled:bg-blue-gray-50 blue-brackets after:con" value={element.note} onChange={()=>{

        onchangeInput(index);
        
        
       }}/> 
       
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
       <br />
       

      </div>
      

       
      )


      })
    }
    
   

    
  </div>
</div>

    </>
    
  )
}

export default AddList
```

[my code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRg0q.png)
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onw0N.png)

Comment: Do you need the list item's color should be changed based on a condition?

Comment: like we are seeing in code edior after some symbol its showing like link 
same as if I write a<>b<>c then b<>c should be in blue remaining part is in black.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for the issue?

Comment: Shorten URL of codesandbox : https://rb.gy/ep51w
Instruction URL of Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r6RXmUM6_XuyHV7N-EDDn0NIRy3tYLcU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try Changing 

const newList = list.slice(ind + 1).map((element) => {
      return <span style={.....your style here}>{element}</span>;
    });